# Nginx 403 fobidden for static files in django

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-config

I deployed my webiste on a linux server but the problem is that css is not loading.

**NGINX**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    # Serve static files
    location /static/ {
        root /home/paul/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Inside of `myproject` I have below directories and file

`myproject(dir-here are settings.py, etc)  env(dir)  manage.py  main(dir)  requirements.txt  static(dir)`

**static**

```
admin(dir)  css(dir)  media(dir)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, on my local computer everything looks ok

Answer (score 0):

At the top of `nginx.conf` I wrote `user [username] staff`. It worked like a charm.